# printing a nested list without brackets and commas work, python

Tags: python, list, printing, nested

```
maze = [["|"," ","|"],[" "," "," "],[" ","_","|"],
          ["|"," "," "],[" "," "," "],[" ","_","|"],
          ["|"," ","|"],[" "," "," "],[" ","X","|"]]
```

How do I print the given list in a such a way that the commas ',' and the brackets '[]' are separated, and there is a new line every three elements. I've tried the code given below, but it doesn't work.

```
  for x in maze:
      print('\n'.join(map(int,maze)))
```

I want the output to be like:

```
| | _|  
|   _|
| |  |
```

basically, it's a maze without the upper and lower roofs

At the same time, How should I represent the upper and lover borders of the maze? Thanks

Comment: `print('\n'.join(map(int,maze)))` Why did you think that code would work?  There aren't any integers in the maze.

Comment: @JohnGordon ah, that was supposed to be str, but I used to represent the maze as 1's and 0's which is why it was set into int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
counter=0
for lst in maze:
    for item in lst:
        print(item,end="")
    counter+=1
    if(counter%3==0):
        print()
```

or use join method:

```
counter=0
for item in maze:
    print("".join(item),end="")
    counter+=1
    if(counter%3==0):
         print()
```

have fun :)